# What's the host param in applets for if when we can use codebase?

Tags: java, applet

what's are the uses of the host param with java applets?

can it be tricked to use a different server than the originating server?

I didn't find a clear complete explanation of the host param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you pass to applets are just like command line parameters to an application: The applet can make whatever use of them that it wants. There's nothing special about a parameter called HOST, and it doesn't cause the applet to do anything magical.

Typically, an applet may like to use the HOST parameter to display, in a status area or something, which host it's being executed from. Or it may behave differently depending on the host... or something.

Unless the applet is signed and given permission in the browser's sandbox, it won't talk to any other host than the one it's loaded from.